# Prove there exist $a, b$ coprime such that $a|r, b|s$ and $lcm(r,s)=ab$ with $r, s\in\Bbb{N}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I just made a proof and I would like to verify it.

**Statement**

> If $r, s \in\Bbb{N} \implies \exists$ $a,b \in\Bbb{Z}$ coprime such that $a|r, b|s$ and $lcm(r,s)=ab$.

**My proof**

> If $r$ and $s$ are coprime, with $a=r$ and $b=s$ we have:
>
> - $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers
> - $a|r$
> - $b|s$
> - $lcm(r,s)=rs=ab$
>
> If $r$ and $s$ are not coprime, since both are greater than $1$ (otherwise they would be coprime) we have that $gcd(r,s)=d\ne 1$.
>
> We can express $r=dq$, $s=dq'$ with $q$ and $q'$ coprime integers. Using the relationship between $lcm$ and $gcd$ we have that $lcm(r,s)=\frac{|rs|}{gcd(r,s)} \implies lcm(r,s)=\frac{dqdq'}{d}=dqq'$.
>
> If $q$ and $d$ are coprime, with $a=q$ and $b=dq'$ we have:
>
> - $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers
> - $a|r$ since $q|dq$
> - $b|s$ since $q'd|q'd$
> - $lcm(r,s)=dqq'=ab$
>
> ***The following part is not correct***
>
> > If $q$ and $d$ are not coprime, let be $gcd(q,d)=l$. With $a=ql$ and $b=\frac{dq'}{l}$ we have:
> >
> > - $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers
> > - $a|r$ since $ql|dq$
> > - $b|s$ since $\frac{q'd}{l}|q'd$
> > - $lcm(r,s)=dqq'=\frac{qlq'd}{l}=ab$
>
> ***This is the corrected (I think) version of the last part***
>
> > If $q$ and $d$ are not coprime: let be $q = \prod_i p_i^{q_i}$ and $d = \prod_i p_i^{d_i}$ the prime factorization of $q$ and $d$ respectively. We define $D=\{i:q_i>0,d_i>0\}$.
> >
> > Let $l = \prod_{i\in D} p_i^{d_i}$
> >
> > Then with $a=ql$ and $b=\frac{dq'}{l}$ we have:
> >
> > - $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers by construction
> > - $a|r$ since $ql|dq$
> > - $b|s$ since $\frac{q'd}{l}|q'd$
> > - $lcm(r,s)=dqq'=\frac{qlq'd}{l}=ab$
>
> $\square$

I wanted to know if my proof is ok and since this exercise belongs to a *'groups - primitive roots'* sheet of exercises, if there is another proof related with those concepts.

Comment: I have nothing to post as an answer but seems everything is right!

Comment: Compare `$a|b$` for $a|b$ with `$a\mid b$` for $a\mid b$. Also, use `$\gcd$` for $\gcd$ and `${\rm lcm}$` for ${\rm lcm}$.

Comment: Adding to @Shaun, also, you may use `$a~|~b$` for $a~|~b$

Comment: Since you asked for alternative proofs, if you use the prime factorization definition of lcm, then there's an almost immediate proof of the result. (It's not quite primitive roots, so I'm not adding it in unless you ask for it)

Comment: Oh what catches my atentiont, please add it. Thank you all.

Comment: You did not prove the claim that $\,a,b\,$ are coprime in the last case.  If you rewrite the lcm as a gcd then it reduces to the dual gcd form in the linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque I just added which I think it's a correction. What do you think of it now?